Looking for an arrow type in tikz-cd: a line with a small circle at the end
I would like to draw an arrow such as \multimap in tikz-cd and such as pictured below.

How can I achieve that?
I have seen the similar question but I would like to use it with tikz-cd.
My aim is to realize commutative diagrams of multimaps.
Thank you for your help.

If all your arrows are circled:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    arrows={>={Circle[open]}}
    }
  
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar[r] & B\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}


If only some of your arrows are circled:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    }
  
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar[r] & B\ar[dl,>={Circle[open]}]\\
C\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}


Of course, you can also create a style:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    multimap/.style={>={Circle[open]}},
    }
  
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar[r] & B\ar[dl,multimap]\\
C\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}

The result is the same as the previous one.

In general, it's better to set the overall arrow style to math font. You can use a different style for specific arrows.
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzcdset{
  arrow style=math font,
  multimap/.style={arrow style=tikz,>={Circle[open]}}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r,multimap] & B \arrow[d] \\
C & D \arrow[l,multimap]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}


Uncommenting \usepackage{newtx} would produce

where the arrow blends with NewTX arrows.
